# Docker образ POSTGRES не подключается к базе и выдает ошибку: "Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified"

Tags: postgresql, docker

Не получается подключить образ POSTGRES в Docker. Система выдает ошибку:

```
Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
       You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the
       superuser. For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".
       You may also use "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust" to allow all
       connections without a password. This is *not* recommended.
       See PostgreSQL documentation about "trust":
       https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
```

На англоязычных форумах найден такой способ, как исправить ошибку:

```
db:
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "db"
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: "trust"
```

Так как работу с виртуальными машинами только начинаю осваивать, не могу понять, где этот код нужно применить. Или есть другой способ, как исправить ошибку?

Comment: А вы через что запускаете контейнер ? Если прямо докером, то переменные окружения передаются прямо в командной строке, с ключом -e, как и показано в сообщении об ошибке. А если используете compose то те строки что нашли пишите в его конфиг

Comment: @Mike  контейнер запускаю через Kitematic. Там есть  Docker CLI, через которую открывается командная строка, но если ввожу строки которые нашла туда,  получаю ошибку "не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программ"

Comment: В документации на Kitematic (https://docs.docker.com/kitematic/userguide/) в разделе "Adding Environment variables" написано что переменные окружения добавляются в “General” “Settings”

Comment: @Mike  да, нашла такой раздел, а для чего добавлять переменные окружения? и что в данном случае нужно добавить?

Comment: Ну например POSTGRES_PASSWORD что бы задать пароль для постгреса

Comment: @Mike получилось, спасибо большое!